# WebSQL: Error processing SQL: number of '?'s in statement string does not match argument count

Tags: javascript, sql, json, storage, web-sql

I want to create a dynamic function to INSERT data into the webSQL Database. I cannot use indexed DB because Zetakey does not support it.

```
 tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO " + table + "(" + formatfields + ")
 VALUES (" + formatqm + ")",
          [formatvalues],
          webdb.onSuccess,
          webdb.onError);
```

Ich übergebe an den Query:

```
formatfields = "one, two"; (up to an undefined number)
formatqm = "?, ?";
formatvalues = "123, 456"; (dynamic user entries for x fields)
```

Can someone tell me what do I have to do with the formatvalues? When I write 123, 456 directly its working fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nobody? Anybody who knows about webSQL and JS?

Comment: array.push was my method =)

Comment: Just to add a note, if you are passing an array as the second argument in executeSql(), drop the square brackets (`[]`). E.g., `tx.executeSql(query, formatvalues, webdb.onSuccess, webdb.onError);`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dynamically create or change table column fields, use JSON serialization of the record. Basically store stringify user given object data on INSERT and parse on retrieval. If you need query over column, initialize those columns only. It will be just like IndexedDB does.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*array.push */

formatvalues = new Array;

formatvalues.push("123");
```

and so on!